# ChromeDriver is outdated, how do i update it?

Tags: python, google-chrome, testing, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Im currently learning Selenium automation with python and im using chromedriver.
Im having an issue running this simple script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=Service(executable_path = 'C:/Users/{UserName}/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64'))
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

The error i receive is

> selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message:
> session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome
> version 114 Current browser version is 118.0.5993.89 with binary path
> C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

How do i resolve this? many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not apply to your environment, but `brew upgrade chromedriver` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome version 15 or newer will need to chromedriver download from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json

Answer (score 0):

Just download the new driver from here
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Find your current Chrome version by typing "chrome://version/" in
   your browser.
2. Download the compatible ChromeDriver from [enter link description here](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/)
3. Replace the old ChromeDriver with the new one:

   For Windows: `move new_chromedriver.exe C:\Windows\path\chromedriver.exe`

   For Linux/Ubuntu: `sudo mv new_chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

This ensures your Selenium script works with the updated ChromeDriver.

Comment: Question: How do if find the old chromedriver? i dont see it anywhere in the environment variables.